# Maximizing GCD with some condition

Tags: java, c++, python-3.x, python-2.7, greatest-common-divisor

This is a problem given in ***HackWithInfy2019*** in hackerrank.
I am stuck with this problem since yesterday.

### Question:

You are given array of N integers.You have to find a pair **(i,j)** 
which **maximizes** the value of **GCD(`a[i],a[j]`)+(`j - i`)**
and 1<=i< j<=n

### Constraints are:

2<= **N** <= 10^5

1<= **a[i]** <= 10^5

I've tried this problem using python

Comment: What are the limits on N and the values of the integers?

Comment: I edited just now u can see it

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that could work:

```
result = 0
min_i = array[1 ... 100000] initialized to 0
for j in [1, 2, ..., n]
    for d in divisors of a[j]
        let i = min_i[d]
        if i > 0
            result = max(result, d + j - i)
        else
            min_i[d] = j
```

Here, `min_i[d]` for each `d` is the smallest `i` such that `a[i] % d == 0`. We use this in the inner loop to, for each `d`, find the first element in the array whose GCD with `a[j]` is at least `d`. When `j` is one of the possible values for which `gcd(a[i], a[j]) + j - i` is maximal, when the inner loop runs with `d` equal to the required GCD, `result` will be set to the correct answer.

The maximum possible number of divisors for a natural number less than or equal to 100,000 is 128 (see [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/14463)). Therefore the inner loop runs at most 128 * 100,000 = 12.8 million times. I imagine this could pass with some optimizations (although maybe not in Python).

(To iterate over divisors, use a sieve to precompute the smallest nontrivial divisor for each integer from 1 to 100000.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

Create a mutable class `MinMax` for storing the min. and max. index.

Create a `Map<Integer, MinMax>` for storing the min. and max. index for a particular divisor.

For each value in `a`, find all divisors for `a[i]`, and update the map accordingly, such that the `MinMax` object stores the min. and max. `i` of the number with that particular divisor.

When done, iterate the map and find the entry with largest result of calculating `key + value.max - value.min`.

The min. and max. values of that entry is your answer.